# parse string into list based on input list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to write a function in python3 to parse a string based on the input list element. The following function works but is there a better way to do it?

```
def func(oStr, s_s):
    if not oStr:
        return s_s
    elif '' in s_s:
        return [oStr]
    else:
        for x in s_s:
            st = oStr.find(x)
            end = st + len(x)
            res.append(oStr[st:end])
            oStr = oStr.replace(x, '')
        if oStr:
            res.append(oStr)
        return res
```

case 1

```
o_str = 'ABCNew York - Address'
s_str = ['ABC']
return ['ABC', 'New York - Address']
```

case 2

```
o_str = 'New York Friend Add |  NumberABCNewYork Name  | FirstName Last Name | time : Jan-31-2017'
s_str = ['New York Friend Add |  Number', 'ABC', 'NewYork Name  | FirstName Last Name | time: Jan-31-2017']
return ['New York Friend Add |  Number', 'ABC', 'NewYork Name  | FirstName Last Name | time: Jan-31-2017']
```

case 3

```
o_str = '-'
s_str = ['']
return ['-']
```

case 4

```
o_str = '1'
s_str = ['']
return ['1']
```

case 5

```
o_str = '1234Family-Name'
s_str = ['1234']
return ['1234', 'Family-Name']
```

case 6

```
o_str = ''
s_str = ['12345667', 'name']
return ['12345667', 'name']
```

Comment: Perhaps [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better site to ask this on, assuming your code works.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you explained what is `o_str` and `s_str` in you code?

Comment: o_str and s_str are just str variable that I would like to parse

Answer (score 0):

To use a string like an array, you would just program it in the same way. For example

```
myStr="Hello, World!"
myString.insert(len(myString),"""Your character here""")
```

For your purposes `.append()` would work exactly the same way. Hope I helped.